# Forwarding a chunked HTTP Response in a service

Tags: java, jetty

I am working on a module that serves as a proxy (for stuff like access-control, etc.) for other REST services. One of the services (lets assume **S**) behind my proxy (**P**) returns chunked response which ranges from 20KB to 5MB.

Within my proxy module when I try to copy the inputStream from **S** into the outputStream of **P** , I run into following exceptions:

`2014-05-29 00:19:49,841 [] - org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
2014-05-29 00:19:49,841 [] - org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
2014-05-29 00:19:49,841 [] -    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:187)
2014-05-29 00:19:49,841 [] -    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.write(WriteFlusher.java:335)
2014-05-29 00:19:49,841 [] -    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractEndPoint.write(AbstractEndPoint.java:125)
2014-05-29 00:19:49,841 [] -    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$ContentCallback.process(HttpConnection.java:639)
2014-05-29 00:19:49,841 [] -    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.iterate(IteratingCallback.java:80)
2014-05-29 00:19:49,841 [] -    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.send(HttpConnection.java:296)
2014-05-29 00:19:49,841 [] -    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.sendResponse(HttpChannel.java:703)
2014-05-29 00:19:49,841 [] -    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.write(HttpChannel.java:733)
2014-05-29 00:19:49,841 [] -    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:294)`

It seems that outputStream closes (broken-pipe error) for some reason, while the inputStream has been partially copied into it.

The copyStream method goes like this -

```
    public static void copyStream(InputStream input, OutputStream output)
        throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;
        if (input == null)
            return;
        while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    }
```

Any pointers on this will be helpful.